# Lighthouse: Uses deprecated APIs

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, lighthouse

Lighthouse report detects Uses deprecated APIs.

`Specifying` overflow: visible `on img, video and canvas tags may cause them to produce visual content outside of the element bounds. See https://github.com/WICG/shared-element-transitions/blob/main/debugging_overflow_on_images.md.`

Website tested: https://giocone.com

Pagespeed often displayed a "!" rating after some scans, but I couldn't find the culprit.